# Probability of getting 2 tails on 3 coin tosses?

Tags: probability

I just learned in class that if you toss 3 coins (a quarter, a dime and a nickel), the probability of getting 2 tails only is $\frac14$ and I don't really understand why.

My first intuition is that:

0 heads => 1 tail

1 head => 2 tails

2 heads => 1 tail

3 heads => 0 tails

Therefore, it should be $\frac14$. I understand that the number of permutations is 8, thus:

HHH THT

HHT THH

HTT TTH

TTT HTH

And if you take those with 2 tails, it's $\frac38$. But where is the flaw in my first reasoning? Why do I care about which coin gets Tails when I only want to know the probability of getting 2 tails?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The three outcomes: (0head, 1head, 2head, 3head) are **not equally likely to occur**, therefore you may not use the "ratio of desirable outcomes compared to total outcomes" method to find the probability.

Comment: Your first sentence confuses me.  "... *the probability of getting 2 tails only is* $\frac{1}{8}$" should be corrected to say either that the probability of getting 2 tails **followed by a head** is $\frac{1}{8}$, the probability of getting 2 tails and a head *in any order* is $\frac{3}{8}$, or the probability of getting 3 tails is $\frac{1}{8}$.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks, that makes sense! But in the case of a experiment where just writing down all the possibilities would be tedious, do you have any tricks on finding out intuitively that they are not equally probable outcomes? Anything that can be a hint in those cases? By the way, made a mistake in the first sentence,should have written 1/4

Comment: @Alexandre One or two tails can happen in three ways each, while all tails or no tails can only happen one way each. You don't need to write them all down to figure that out, and even for more complicated settings, it's usually easy to reason that at least the number of ways each case can happen is _different_.

Comment: In general you should always assume that you **don't know** that outcomes are equally likely to begin with.  Only if you can prove or are told explicitly that they are equally likely can you continue using the ratio method.  If you cannot prove they are equally likely, chances are the answer to the question being asked would be "not enough information to conclude anything."

Comment: Alright, understood! Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: I would also question the bit 'I learned in class'. Maybe the teacher made a mistake and said 'three' instead of 'two' tosses? For two tosses, the probability is 1/4. For three tosses it is 3/8. All assuming fair coins.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to find the right way to apply the [principle of indifference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_indifference). It's not entirely unreasonable to consider applying it to the number of tails thrown. In a Bayesian context, if you didn't know how to calculate the probability distribution for the number of tails, you might assign a subjective probability of $\frac14$ to each possibility since you have no way of judging one to be more probable than another. However, this would only be a reflection of your subjective beliefs. There's no objective symmetry in the situation that dictates that the different numbers of tails should be equiprobable.

By contrast, there's a manifest symmetry between heads and tails (disregarding small differences between the designs on the two sides of the coins), which dictates that these two results must be objectively equiprobable. This is part of the implicit premise of the question that these are *fair* coins. If it weren't part of what you know about the situation that the coins are fair, and you had no way of knowing to which side the coins might be biased, you could still apply the principle of indifference and assign the same probability to the two outcomes – but that would then again be an assignment of subjective probabilities based on your subjective beliefs.

Since in the present case we do assume that you know that the coins are fair, the objective symmetry between heads and tails trumps whatever subjective inclination you may have to consider the numbers of tails equiprobable. As you've shown using the $8$ different combinations, the different numbers of tails are not equiprobable, and once you know this, there's no longer any reason to apply the principle of indifference to them – you're no longer indifferent, and there's no symmetry between them that would force you to be indifferent and would produce a contradiction between the two different applications of the principle of indifference.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you toss a coin, you can get either head or tail.

First toss: $\frac{1}{2}$ Head and $\frac{1}{2}$ Tail.

Namely you have $50\%$ probability for each outcome.

But when you toss the coin again, namely two times in a row, you get:

$$\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{4}$$

and for three times in a row:

$$\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{8}$$

You get this because you are tossing coins one after another, and not all together!

There is a huge difference.

Indeed, if you toss all the three coins together, you can obtain the possibilities you mentioned:

- H H H
- H H T
- H T T
- H T H
- T H H
- T T H
- T T T
- T H T

And only in $3$ cases out of $8$, namely $3/8$ you have two heads (or two tails).

Comment: But if you toss three identical coins in the air simultaneously, then (unless they are identical in the quantum mechanical sense) you still get $\frac38$ probability of two heads. So the temporal component here is not relevant.

Comment: @Arthur Yes, indeed: it's $3/8$ and not $1/8$, if you toss them all together. I don't get your point.

Comment: @Arthur There is a huge difference between tossing one after another and all together.

Comment: The only difference between throwing the coins all together and throwing them one by one is conceptual: it's easier to imagine what happens and do the correct calculations. The actual mathematics are exactly the same.

Comment: @Arthur You get different results so the maths is not the same.

Comment: No, you really don't. Throwing three coins simultaneously or throwing three coins one after the other, the result is still the same: $\frac 18$ probability for each of three heads and for three tails, while two heads and two tails each have probability $\frac38$.

Comment: @FourierTransform Coins do *not* loose their identity when tossed simultaneously.  They remain distinct objects even if an observer is unable to distinguish between them.

Comment: @GrahamKemp wrong.

Comment: @FourierTransform Nope. The probability of getting exactly two heads when three fair coins are thrown simultaneously is $3/8$.  Each coin has a probability of $1/2$ for being a head, or for being a tail, and there are three coins that could be the head.  An observer not being able to identify the coins does not change that.  (Or do you think if we lightly marked the coins with flourescent ink that it would change their behaviour under UV light?)